# Using Rsync to sync Mac to Synology NAS - File owner and group getting changed

Tags: bash, permissions, operating-system, rsync, synology

I have a DS218+ Synology NAS and Mac.  I am successful in being able to sync the two with rsync but during the process the folder/file owner and group get changed.

Initially I let rsync create the folder by not appending a / to the end of the paths.  In this case I got an owner and group as numbers 502 & 20 respectively.  I adjusted by adding the / and creating the top level folder on the NAS via the DSM.  Initially the NAS folder has the correct owner and group but post rsync it goes back to numbers as indicated above.

```
rsync -rltgoDvh --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r --delete  --exclude='.DS_Store' /Users/Chris/CDs/ user@ipaddress::NetBackup/CDs/
```

I would like the folder/file owner and group to be as if they were created by that account locally on the NAS.  My next guess will be to remove "go" from the options in the rsync command but thought someone smarter than me might see through to the correct approach.

Comment: A stupid question here — the above requires the `rsyncd` daemon to be running on the Synology NAS, right? Otherwise, you'd need to go through the ssh port. I actually prefer that (because I don't like many ports open), but, alas, Synology requires me to use a password (as opposed to a secure key), which means — no automation possible.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding your requirement, but `-p`/`--perms` preserves the original file permissions.

I normally use `-a`/`--archive` mode, which is equivalent to `-rlptgoD`, according to `man rsync`.